# Longest repeating substring suffix tree dfs

Tags: java, string, algorithm, tree

I'm having some trouble implementing this. I know I need to do a depth first search to find the deepest path which will give the index of the substring. Having some problems implementing the dfs, probably my poor understanding:

```
int getDeepestPath(TreeNode node)
{
    int maxDistance = 0;
    TreeNode maxNode;
    if(node == null) return 0;
    System.out.println(node.getSuffix());
    if(node.getSuffix() != -1) return 0;  
    else
    {
        TreeNode nextNode = node.getChild();
        while(true)
        {
            int distance = 0;
            if(nextNode != null)
            {
                distance = (nextNode.getRightLabel() -nextNode.getLeftLabel()) + 1;
                System.out.println(distance + " distance");
                distance = getDeepestPath(nextNode,t2Info) + distance;
                if(distance > maxDistance) maxDistance = distance;
                nextNode = nextNode.getSibling();
            }
            else break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(maxDistance);
    return maxDistance;
}
```

the eventual aim is to store the deepest node and the length of the path-I'm just trying to print the length of the path at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain what is "suffix", "child", "right label", "left label" and "sibling" of the tree node?

Comment: yes-child is the first child of the node (the head of a linked list), sibling is a node which shares the parent of the current node, left and right label are used for the short edge labels indexes of the suffix tree

Comment: Should mention that get suffix == -1 means the node is a branch

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just implement DFS with a stack and add a variable to `node` called `visited`. Everytime you push node to stack, mark `visited = true`. Pseudo Code

```
root.visited = true;
root.push()
while(Stack.isEmpty()) {
  if(!root.next.visited) {
    root.next.push()
  }
}
```

Implement the logic for finding the leaf, going to the next branch and for poping. 
This is a generic logic, if you have a binary tree, you can alter this and make it more simple for just two children (left and right)

Comment: I just read your code again, are you just looking for the deepest (longest) branch? I.E the height of the tree?

Comment: Well, if you can't add that simple variable then the the algorithm might become a bit complex (heavy on memory too). Something like store every node's children in a list and traverse the list. In this case, the number of lists wil be == number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong.

In a suffix tree each node should contain a list of keys for the strings that terminate on that node. If the list is empty, then no string is defined by that node. There is no need to find the long path in the tree. For example, if there are three strings in the tree, "app" (1), "apple" (2) and (5), and "apple pie" (3), then the tree will look like:

```
"app" 1  
  |  
"le" 2, 5  
  |  
" pie" 3
```

Comment: The assumption that "I need to do a depth first search to find the deepest path which will give the index of the substring"

Comment: Finding the deepest branch node will give the index of the longest repetitive substring.

Comment: No it won't. In a suffix tree each node can represent multiple characters, so you could have a string like "hyperbolic" be only two nodes deep ("hyper" and "bolic") whereas a string like "apple" might be spread out over five nodes ("a", "p", "p", "l", "e"), so "apple" is 5 nodes deep and "hyperbolic" is only 2 nodes deep.

Comment: Actually, if the Suffix tree is *not* compact, then each node references only 1 character, so drunkmonkey's statement is correct.  However, typically a Suffix tree is compact, as Tyler Durden describes.  But this statement -- no matter if a Suffix Tree is compact or not -- is true: "the longest repeated substring of txt[1..n] is indicated by the deepest fork node in the suffix tree, where depth is measured by the number of characters traversed from the root" (from http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/)